# Serial communication programs - C vs Python

Tags: python, communication, pyserial

I have an MCU, which responds through serial communication. My issue is the following: The code worked last week.

```
ser = serial.Serial(3,115200)
b = ser.write('\x5A\x03\x02\x02\x02\x09')
print b
time.sleep(1)
c = ser.read(7)
print c.encode('hex')
```

This is supposed to print a bunch of bytes read from the MCU. However today, I am reading all the random bytes which I am not supposed to read. Once in a while I read the exact bytes that I am supposed to read. I initially thought it is a problem with my Laptop SERIAL PORTS. However my friend with his program written in C on the same laptop - was able to read it properly. So, I dont know what the question is here - just a problem I dont know how to troubleshoot. My python code is very basic, it should work. Any thoughts on what would be going on is really appreciated.

Comment: its often useful to do a `ser.flush` before writting ... other than that i have no idea ... i have used serial alot and this looks fine ...

Comment: I read about it, but no idea what it does - I believe there are inputflush and outputflush. After reading online I am still illeterate. I used ser.flush() - I am getting the same problem

Comment: What could have changed between last week and this week? Any settings on the MCU, or your computer's serial port? If on Windows you can type `mode` in command line to see all the settings -  try typing this before and after running your program, and before and after running your friend's program, and see if there are any differences in the settings

Comment: The major difference I found is - after running my program I can list all the COMPORTS when I type in mode. But after my friends program - I cannot list all the COMPORTS. I only get - status for device CON

Comment: This isn't actually a python language problem (the code's not wrong). Are you sure the serial port name/number is correct? Are you sure the baudrate is correct? How many bytes are waiting to be read in the serial port buffer?

Comment: 7 bytes should be waiting to be read. Some times it is 7 some times it is like 1000's. Few other times it is 7 but wrong bytes. I am sure of everything else. BASICALLY, once in a while these 7 bytes are wrong - not what I expect them to be.

Comment: I actually understand the problem. I got to know that, the person who coded the MCU, has written a code such a way that the MCU will respond back continuously every 200ms, if there is no read communication from my program.